# How to access a length of a value in a dictionary in Python 3?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary which is

```
{'a01': 2, 'a02': 0, 'a03': 4}
```

How do I get the length of the value of `'a01'`?

That means I need to get the length of value 2

Comment: Integers don't have length.

Comment: Do you mean `dictionary_name['a01']`? This would fetch you the value `2` for the given `key` 'a01'.

Comment: Did you mix up key and value? To get the length of a string, use len: "len({1:'abc'}[1])" is 3. Or doe you mean the absolute value of the integers (function abs) as length?

Comment: I mean I need the length of value of the key 'a01' thx

Comment: And how do you select the key? Do you know the value to search for? As I wrote before, getting the length of a string is easy. But looking up a key by it's value is not what dictionaries are made for (so it's possible, but difficult and expensive)

Comment: Is English maybe not your first language? (totally fine, you speak it better than I speak any other language!)  I think everyone's a little confused as to what you're trying to do.  Can you tell us what value you think you should be getting?  Like, for 'a01', are you hoping to get back the number 2, and for 'a02' hoping to get 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the length for display purposes etc. Convert it to a str first

```
>>> d = {'a01': 2, 'a02': 0, 'a03': 4}
>>> len(str(d['a01']))
1
```

If they keys/values are transposed and you really mean the length of the 'a01' string

```
{0: 'a02', 2: 'a01', 4: 'a03'}
>>> len(d[2])
3
```